Prolog Syntax for Dependent Conditions
First off, I am new to Prolog, so please go easy on me... Also, I am using SWI-Prolog,
so I want to use the correct syntax for SWI.
In this case, I want to define step-parents (specifically step-mother and step-father).
My current syntax is this:
isStepFather(X, Y):-
    dif(X, Y),
    isMale(X),
    not(isParent(X, Y)),
    isMother(Z, Y), isHusband(X, Z).

First off, I know that sometimes "not" is "\=" or some other slash combination, so is there a better version of my "not" statement? Also, the last line is supposed to read like:
"X is a StepFather of Y, if Z is a mother of Y, and X is a Husband of Z."
I want to specify the 2 Z-statements as a single idea/condition, so I put them on the same row, but does that matter? Or is there a better way of chaining two conditions that are linked to each other, but not necessarily to the other conditions?
Finally, would it be better/more elegant to use
isWife(Z, X)
instead of
isHusband(X, Z)
so that Z stays in the front of both statements?
Please let me know your feedback!

You are making your life more difficult by using variable names of X, Y, and Z, rather than meaningful names such as Mother, Father, Child.

I can see that easily being the case in more complex code, but I wanted to think about this abstractly. For instance, it would be easy to say is_father(Father, Son):- dif(Father, Son), is_male(Father), is_male(Son). But putting it abstractly like X, Y, Z kinda forces me to think "what exactly makes any given person the father of any given other person." For instance, "Son" might actually be a daughter.

2 reasonable ways spring to mind:
stepfather_child(SF, C) :-
    mother_child(M, C),
    husband_wife(SF, M),
    \+ father_child(SF, C).

... and:
stepfather_child_alt(SF, C) :-
    dif(F, SF),
    mother_father_child(M, F, C),
    husband_wife(SF, M).

Some programming notes:

Meaningful variable names are far more helpful than meaningless names
\+ is only safe when the variables are ground, so move it to be after clauses which will make the variables ground
For a bit of performance improvement, move dif clauses to be before they could be pointlessly-often called due to backtracking
Predicate names which describe their arguments are very elegant and convenient, especially given Prolog's relational nature
Classification is an art form, e.g. why have parent or person and then need some other way of knowing something as fundamental as male or female, when e.g. husband_wife or mother_father_child makes it obvious by their placement - could make it more specific with e.g. mother_father_daughter and mother_father_son
It seems a bit more readable to have predicate names like_this rather than likeThis, so that capitalized variables stand out.


(1) The isMale / isFemale idea was to guard again searches returning results of the wrong gender, just like how the dif() would guard against a person being their own parent/child/sibling.            (2) I intend to use Prolog as a logic engine in future applications (I come from C++ among others), so names like mother_father_son(M, F, S) are confusing to read when I want to check if a woman is the mother of any children. Hence my syntax with isMother. Qt and C# do this syntax often, plus it is easier for me to read as isMother(sandra, Child) -> true = sandra is the mother of some Child.

Such things are relations, like tables and fields in a SQL database. Writing Prolog code in a procedural style is like buying a Ferrari to use as a tractor :-)

As usual, the most difficult part of learning a new language is rewiring your brain to think in that language's style. I'll keep that in mind moving forward.
